# Query based on keys of firestore Map

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm writing a cloud function which updates a sibling collection onUpdate. I have the follwong:

```
await db.collection(
          `users/${userId}/rosters`).where(
          "athletes.keys", "array-contains", bid).get();
```

where "athletes" is a map attribute in each document in rosters. Does this logic not work? Is there some other way to do it?
Thanks!!

Comment: Please provide more details on what you are trying to achieve. Also what does the var bid look like ?

Answer (score 2):

Firestore queries support dot notation interpretation, allowing target paths such as `athletes.keys` to be filtered. This does require an [index to be generated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) if one is not already and the path cannot be dynamic. For example: `"athletes.users." + user.id` is not valid.

Some answers for reference

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63536480/2301161
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55554195/2301161

Comment: The second part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66838632/3068190) may also be useful for searching bids in a document, just replace "members" with "bids".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers, I realize now I'm being silly and can use the map trick. This will return all rosters which contain a matching key in athletes.

```
 db.collection(
          `users/${userId}/rosters`).where(
          `athletes.${bid}`, ">=", "").get();
```

Sam's solution would also work by adding an "exists" key.