# Multiple Where clause in firestore on Map in Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, where-clause

I am creating a social app using firestore like Instagram or Twitter where user can see posts of the users they follow on their wall.

Firestore `whereArrayContains`|`whereArrayContainsAny` only works for 10 items, whereas a user can ***follow more than 10 people***. So I decided to use map filter as done here.

```
postCollection
        - postID_1
                - First Post By Person 1
                - createdBy 
                     person_1_ID = true 
        - postID_2
                - Second Post By Person 1
                - createdBy 
                     person_1_ID = true 
        - postID_3
                - Third Post By Person 1
                - createdBy 
                     person_1_ID = true 
        - postID_4
                - First Post By Person 2
                - createdBy 
                     person_2_ID = true
```

Code

```
    val fs = Firebase.firestore
    var query  = fs.collection("postCollection").whereEqualTo("createdBy.person_1_ID",true)
    query = query.whereEqualTo("createdBy.person_2_ID",true)
    query.get().addOnSuccessListener {
        val mList = it.toObjects(PostBO::class.java)
    }
```

Above code working for single

```
whereEqualTo("createdBy.person_1_ID",true)
```

I have seen multiple post on stackoverflow [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036975/firestore-multiple-conditional-where-clauses) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987399/firestore-search-array-contains-for-multiple-values)

Or suggest a better structure for handling.

Show recent post for those to whom I follow.

**2nd Approach**

```
var query  = fs.collection("postCollection")
query = query.whereEqualTo("createdBy", hashMapOf(
    ///"person_2_ID" to true,
    "person_1_ID" to true
))
query = query.whereEqualTo("createdBy", hashMapOf(
    "person_2_ID" to true
))
query.get().addOnSuccessListener {
    val mList = it.toObjects(PostBO::class.java)
    mList.forEach { _ ->

    }
}
```

Have a look at my Document below
[image]

Still not working for multiple `WhereEqual`.

**Edit after AlexMamo Answer**

You solution doesn't work. Just for testing purpose I added a node to test and operation like below still give me no data at all.

```
postCollection
        - postID_1
                - First Post By Person 1 and Person 2 both
                - createdBy 
                     person_1_ID = true 
                     person_2_ID = true
```

Your answer also don't work for **AND operation** as well. But I need **OR operation**

Query working for And Operation is written below.

```
val query  = fs.collection("testCollection")
            .whereEqualTo("createdBy.person_1_ID", true)
            .whereEqualTo("createdBy.person_2_ID",true)
        query.get().addOnSuccessListener {
            val mList = it.toObjects(PostBO::class.java)
            mList.forEach { _ ->
                //
            }
        }
```

Comment: So what's wrong with using those approaches?

Comment: Data is not populating if I apply two where clause. It's working for only one whereEqualTo

Comment: Are you using any orderBy?

Comment: No. I am not using any orderBy. I am using the same code that I shared above

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added picture of the document as well

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll write you an answer wight away.

Comment: @AlexMamo is there any solution in android for it or not ?

Comment: Yes, the one that exists in the duplicate.